# Android sound recorder bad performance

Tags: android, audio

```
        //constructor
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
        /////////////

        //thread run() method
            int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N*10);
                        recorder.startRecording();

    while(!stopped)
                { 
                try {
                           //if not paused upload audio
                   if (uploadAudio == true) {

                           short[][] buffers  = new short[256][160];
                           int ix = 0;

                            //allocate buffer for audio data
                            short[] buffer = buffers[ix++ % buffers.length];

                               //write audio data to track
                           N = recorder.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);

                           //create bytes big enough to hold audio data
                           byte[] bytes2 = new byte[buffer.length * 2];

                                   //convert audio data from short[][] to byte[]

ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(buffer);


                        //encode audio data for ulaw
                                read(bytes2, 0, bytes2.length);
```

See [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/speech/srec/UlawEncoderInputStream.java.shtml) for ulaw encoder code.  Im using the read, maxAbsPcm and encode methods

```
                                //send audio data
                                //os.write(bytes2,0,bytes2.length);
                            }
                        } finally {
                    }
                }
                os.close();
            }
            catch(Throwable x)
            { 
                Log.w("AudioWorker", "Error reading voice AudioWorker", x);
            }
            finally
            { 
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            }

        ///////////
```

So this works ok.  The audio is sent in the proper format to the server and played at the opposite end.  However the audio skips often.  Example: saying 1,2,3,4 will play back with the 4 cut off.
I believe it to be a performance issue because I have timed some of these methods and when they take 0 or less seconds everything works but they quite often take a couple seconds.  With the converting of bytes and encoding taking the most.
Any idea how I can optimize this code to get better performance?  Or maybe a way to deal with lag (possibly build a cache)?

Comment: Hi! I have a similar problem than you encode/decoding to ulaw. Did you fix your problem? Could you provide me how encode/decode to ulaw/pcmu properly, pleas?